PL/SQL Error:" POST: PROCEDURE DOESN'T EXIST" when calling it from other procedure
I'm trying to create a database web interface for inserting new data from web. Everything is a part of of Oracle sql database package Currently I have 2 procedures: procedure test2 should call procedure createplace using POST, but I keep getting error message. Can anyone explain where is the mistake and how to solve it?
PROCEDURE test2 IS
    CURSOR c_data IS
        SELECT place_id, city_id, place_name
        FROM places;

    v_place_id NUMBER;
    v_city_id NUMBER;
    v_place_name VARCHAR2(100); -- Adjust the size as needed

BEGIN
    menu(2);
    htp.htmlopen;           -- generates <HTML>
    htp.headopen;           -- generates <HEAD>
    htp.headclose;          -- generates </HEAD>
    htp.bodyopen;           -- generates <BODY>


    -- Create an HTML form
    htp.formopen('POST', 'CREATEPLACE');
    htp.p('Place ID:');
    htp.formText('place_id', v_place_id);
    htp.br;
    htp.p('City ID:');
    htp.formText('city_id', v_city_id);
    htp.br;
    htp.p('Place Name:');
    htp.formText('place_name', v_place_name);
    htp.br;
    htp.formsubmit('Submit');
    htp.formclose;

    htp.bodyclose;          -- generates </BODY>
    htp.htmlclose;          -- generates </HTML>
END test2;

PROCEDURE CREATEPLACE (
    p_place_id IN NUMBER,
    p_city_id IN NUMBER,
    p_place_name IN VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    -- Increment the ID and insert a new record
    INSERT INTO Places (Place_id, city_id, place_name)
    VALUES (p_place_id, p_city_id, p_place_name);
END CREATEPLACE;


What have you read that leads you to believe formopen will call a PL/SQL procedure?

@JeffHolt CHAT GPT

Maybe I'm too old-school but I would never use AI for that. Ever.

using the htp packages for writing a web interface is over 25 years old. Even if you get it to work, it is greatly discouraged (no security included, you'll have to do everything yourself). Maybe consider using Oracle APEX if you want to write a web application on an oracle database.
